# Timer Help:Working on a project for my AP Computer Science class

Tags: java

In our class we are making a game. The user has to Guess words and stuff. I don't think info about the game is needed to answer my question/problem.
Ok so what I am trying to do is to give the user a time limit in which they have to guess the word. Something like 15 seconds. If the user does not guess the word in 15 seconds they lose a turn.
Problems:

1. We didn't learn how to use timers. I experiment with timers and stuff. I can get a timer to count down from 15.
2. I can't check the current time while waiting for the user to input a guess.
3. I don't know how to bypass `Stdin.readString()` and make the program check the time.

Thanks.

Comment: Context can be important.  I assume that this is a console program and not a GUI, correct?  And what is Stdin? readString()?

Comment: Did you learn about threading at all? If not, maybe you're supposed to do the timer in a while() loop that also checks for input. It isn't a good way to do it but maybe the purpose of the program is to show the limitations of a single thread.

Comment: Stdin.readString() is how we learned to read Strings from users. 

It is not a GUI its just a text based program.

I don't know what threading is either

Comment: If the assignment does not mandate you to use a `Timer` (in which case, you'll need to dip your feet in concurrency (threading)), I highly recommend you drop that feature.

Comment: @Sam U I agree with Bart Kiers. Do you NEED a Timer? No need to make this more complicated than it has to be.

Comment: I don't need a timer. It seemed like a cool extra option. Its probably too above my level, thanks everyone!

Comment: @Sam U  Well, you still have lots of good suggestions for Timers and Threads, for if you want to try in the future :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to gather input from the user.

You may want to avoid timers if you don't know what threading is yet, but if you do want to try, you might be interested looking into the [TimerTask & Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/class-use/TimerTask.html) classes.

While you may already know, you can get time from the System class, like [currentTimeMillis](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)

Comment: so why would the scanner help?

Comment: @Sam U I wager your Stdin object is probably a wrapper for the Scanner class. I was just offering it as a possible documented alternative

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. As you said, your program is waiting for input and hence that *thread* is busy. What you can do is create a separate thread, pass your timer to that thread and have it check the timer. Perhaps something like the following:

```
public class TimerChecker implements Runnable {
    private Timer timer;
    public TimerChecker(Timer timer) { this.timer = timer; }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      // implement logic here
    }
}
```

Which you can have invoked in a new thread using:

```
 Timer timer = ...
 new Thread(new TimerChecker(timer)).start();
 // Now you are free to perform your blocking operation in the current thread
 Stdin.readString();
```

Comment: this looks help full but is really confusing

Comment: Each thread can run simultanous to another thread. Hence, if one thread is blocked reading user input, the other thread can still move freely. Here, the `TimerChecker` can perform actions (e.g., check the time) while your original thread is hung waiting for user input. Have a glance at the [java threading guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is, well to a run a separate thread object for the timer... this thread shall handle the updating of the time and would then trigger a certain event when the time of the player runs out...

or more like, implementing a counter in a separate thread whose increments are triggered by time-step, in this case, in seconds, you can do this by calling sleep()..

the timer thread object shall maintain a variable which keeps track of the current time..

on the main method of your program, you shall continue to check the value of this variable, as a pre-condition of your main loop perhaps,

the idea is there i think, just a thought!

pseudocode

```
class Timer extends Thread{
    int current_time = 0;

    public void run(){
     sleep(1000);
     current_time += 1;
    }

    public void synchronized getCurTime(){
     return current_time;
    }
}



class Game{

  public Game(){

   Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.start();

   while (timer.getCurTime() <16){
      //get the guess of the user
      //checks if it's correct
      // if it is correct, output you win and break!
   }

  //time runs out

  }
```

}

Comment: everyone keeps talking about threads, i guess my question should be how do you use/what is a thread?

Comment: if your parent is a process, then you are your parents thread... thread is another piece of execution, in the same memory space i think of the process that invokes it...

Answer (score 0):

How about an Event driven architecture with [Java eventing library](http://code.google.com/p/javaeventing)?

[Example of events with conditions](http://code.google.com/p/javaeventing/wiki/Examples).